# problem with passing datetime to reporting service from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i'm using SSRS2008 and asp.net on VS2008 SP1.

i have found a problem when i tried to pass parameter from asp.net to reporting service.

in my c# code, i added report parameter with date value of "05/01/2011" ( 1 May 2011 ) but it became "5 Jan 2011" in rdl file instead.

is it possible that this problem might come from different regional/system locale setting in server?
because i did not found this problem on my development computer which was set to US location.

Please give me any suggestion on this issue.

Thanks in adv.

vcha

Comment: Server most likely have a different date format. Can you check/change the date format of the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are passing the date as a string? In that case I have had most success bypassing date format internationalisation problems by using a military style date format of "YYYY-MM-DD". In your example, your date would be "2011-05-01". Reporting Services always decodes this date format correctly.